# Theres something wrong with my viewport shading

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, light, lighting, shadows

I'm a beginner and I was making a house while I found a problem. When I turn on the *Scene World* in viewport shading, weird shadow casts and my house turns black

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

The default in viewport shading uses an HDRI, which is an image that emits light from all angles, but your scene world has very low light, other than your area light that is pointing straight down.  The house "turns black" because nothing is lighting it.  You can go to the world properties and increase the strength of the world light or add an HDRI to your world.